# Why does my nested for loop not run in a case where it is 3 layers down, but it does when it is 2 layers down?

Tags: python, for-loop

Since the initial question was too complex, I have made it shorter to simplify. Additionally I have found the issue and provided the answer below.

The problem:
the `for article in results` loop does not run.

The cause: `print(f"{compName} has {len(list(results))} articles")`

As of today I have no clue why that print causes the for loop to be ignored.

```
for org in industryList:
    articleList = []
    articleInfo = []
    for comp in org:
        query = f"certain query here {compName}"
        results = ["results from query"]
        print(f"{compName} has {len(list(results))} articles")

        for article in results:
            print("test")
```

Comment: You should try simplifying your code to make it easier for people to understand it quickly and help you. Right now it's just too big and it's unlikely someone is going to waste several minutes trying to understand what's going on. Try removing everything unnecessary from the code, while still reproducing the issue.

Comment: It's hard to tell without running the code, and this code isn't runnable as is.  I think I see a bug, however: because of the placement of the inner loops (and the fact articleList and articleInfo are never reset), articleInfo is going to be HUGE!  Imagine having 3 `comp` in `org`.  The first `comp`, the results will be appended to articleList, which will then append to articleInfo.  The second `comp`, the results will be appended to articleList (which still contains the first list), and then all will again be appended to articleInfo.  I think that you can see this growing wildly.

Comment: @coreyp_1 unfortunately that's a feature and not a bug. I need all comps belonging in an org in the same org file.

Comment: @Shandorius  Suppose that you have 3 comps.  Comp 1 has pubmed results A and B,  Comp 2 has results C and D, and Comp 3 has results E and F.  ArticleInfo will be a list which contains duplicates.  In this example (because of the way that the code is structured) it will contain [A,B,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,E,F].

Comment: @coreyp_1 ahhh I didnt even realise that thanks! Although I am afraid that I will have to rewrite the code anyways as I cant get it to work. It seems to be a conflict with the package I am using.

Comment: @coreyp_1 for some reason the problem was the print() in front of the "for article in results" loop. I will never understand why

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is the `print(f"{compName} has {len(list(results))} articles")` line.

As of today I have no clue why that print causes the for loop to be ignored.